# Symfony2 error handling independent for each one of the modules in the page

Tags: symfony, exception

I have a screen displaying a complex layout that shows several different modules, portlet kind each of them is a different twig template and a controller call.

In case of exception from one of the controllers call, i want to fill this square with a brief excerpt from log (if its configured in that way), but i want other modules to be displayed normally, and js plugins working. There will be a small square in the middle of the page blank or showing the log. I'm not working with ESI.

So far I've tried to apply different approaches:
 - an exception listener, where I can obtain an stack trace and show a custom error twig template
 - using an "alt" controller call from the previous twig controller render

I've seen I cannot mix this two approaches,
  - when using "alt" there no event raised, nothing to listen, alternative controller has no info about exception to show
  - without "alt", my error template is shows full screen, so no other modules are shown.
  - the same with the standard ouput error or even if I override ExceptionController.

In this moment I'm considering these options
  - "alt", for every controller call in the page, keep in APC the profile token number for this request (I couldn't achieve yet),  in order to use it from the alternative controller and search logs at profile collector
  - exception listener together and "alt", find in the framework when error is detected, raise event but also launch "alt", and make it compatible.

any help will be appreciated